# Wi-Fi stops working from time to time

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, network-manager, iwlwifi

I have Ubuntu 16.04 installed on my Lenovo Thinkpad E560 laptop.
From time to time the wifi somehow stops working. I can see it is "connected"
to router, but when trying to reconnect, it does not find any routers. I tried restarting the network-manager, but unfortunately the problem persists.
Today, I noticed it crashed when the screen was off and I tried to connect charger - but I believe it crashes sometimes when I am not doing anything with charger.

```
$ lshw -class network
  *-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: wlp1s0
   version: 99
   serial: 00:db:df:8b:68:e3
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-139-generic firmware=17.352738.0 ip=192.168.0.107 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
   resources: irq:127 memory:e1200000-e1201fff
```

```
$ dmesg log
    [18630.979262] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[18630.979271] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 0 at /build/linux-PrHwV2/linux-4.4.0/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwl-trans.h:1058 iwl_pcie_txq_stuck_timer+0x2c9/0x3a0 [iwlwifi]()
[18630.979272] Modules linked in: hid_generic usbhid hid ipt_MASQUERADE nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4 nf_conntrack_netlink nfnetlink xfrm_user xfrm_algo iptable_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_nat_ipv4 xt_addrtype iptable_filter ip_tables xt_conntrack x_tables nf_nat nf_conntrack br_netfilter bridge stp llc drbg ansi_cprng ctr ccm aufs overlay bnep snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_conexant snd_hda_codec_generic arc4 intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel iwlmvm snd_soc_skl snd_soc_skl_ipc snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_sst_ipc aesni_intel snd_soc_sst_dsp mac80211 aes_x86_64 lrw snd_soc_core gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper uvcvideo cryptd snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops dw_dmac_core
[18630.979299]  videobuf2_v4l2 snd_hda_intel videobuf2_core joydev v4l2_common input_leds snd_hda_codec iwlwifi videodev snd_hda_core snd_hwdep media cfg80211 snd_pcm rtsx_pci_ms memstick serio_raw i2c_i801 btusb btrtl btbcm btintel bluetooth shpchp thinkpad_acpi mei_me nvram snd_seq_midi mei snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer snd soundcore mac_hid binfmt_misc parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 rtsx_pci_sdmmc amdkfd amd_iommu_v2 radeon i915_bpo intel_ips ttm i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper e1000e psmouse syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt ptp fb_sys_fops pps_core drm ahci rtsx_pci libahci wmi fjes video
[18630.979327] CPU: 0 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/0 Tainted: G        W       4.4.0-139-generic #165-Ubuntu
[18630.979328] Hardware name: LENOVO 20EV001BXS/20EV001BXS, BIOS R00ET38W (1.13 ) 02/24/2016
[18630.979329]  0000000000000286 a395f935d4ee2bf5 ffff880242403da8 ffffffff81405543
[18630.979331]  0000000000000000 ffffffffc0791108 ffff880242403de0 ffffffff810850d2
[18630.979333]  000000000000001e ffff880232f84200 ffff880232f84000 0000000000a02eac
[18630.979335] Call Trace:
[18630.979336]  <IRQ>  [<ffffffff81405543>] dump_stack+0x63/0x90
[18630.979342]  [<ffffffff810850d2>] warn_slowpath_common+0x82/0xc0
[18630.979344]  [<ffffffff8108521a>] warn_slowpath_null+0x1a/0x20
[18630.979348]  [<ffffffffc07797f9>] iwl_pcie_txq_stuck_timer+0x2c9/0x3a0 [iwlwifi]
[18630.979352]  [<ffffffffc0779530>] ? iwl_pcie_txq_unmap+0x100/0x100 [iwlwifi]
[18630.979355]  [<ffffffff810f2197>] call_timer_fn+0x37/0x130
[18630.979358]  [<ffffffffc0779530>] ? iwl_pcie_txq_unmap+0x100/0x100 [iwlwifi]
[18630.979360]  [<ffffffff810f297d>] run_timer_softirq+0x23d/0x2f0
[18630.979361]  [<ffffffff81089f79>] __do_softirq+0x109/0x2b0
[18630.979363]  [<ffffffff8108a295>] irq_exit+0xa5/0xb0
[18630.979366]  [<ffffffff8185ade0>] smp_apic_timer_interrupt+0x50/0x60
[18630.979368]  [<ffffffff8185873f>] apic_timer_interrupt+0xbf/0xd0
[18630.979369]  <EOI>  [<ffffffff816e6cbe>] ? cpuidle_enter_state+0x11e/0x2d0
[18630.979374]  [<ffffffff816e6cad>] ? cpuidle_enter_state+0x10d/0x2d0
[18630.979375]  [<ffffffff816e6ea7>] cpuidle_enter+0x17/0x20
[18630.979377]  [<ffffffff810c93c2>] call_cpuidle+0x32/0x60
[18630.979379]  [<ffffffff816e6e89>] ? cpuidle_select+0x19/0x20
[18630.979381]  [<ffffffff810c9686>] cpu_startup_entry+0x296/0x360
[18630.979383]  [<ffffffff8184b2ac>] rest_init+0x7c/0x80
[18630.979386]  [<ffffffff81f64016>] start_kernel+0x483/0x4a4
[18630.979388]  [<ffffffff81f63120>] ? early_idt_handler_array+0x120/0x120
[18630.979390]  [<ffffffff81f63339>] x86_64_start_reservations+0x2a/0x2c
[18630.979391]  [<ffffffff81f63485>] x86_64_start_kernel+0x14a/0x16d
[18630.979392] ---[ end trace c799081da7567a6d ]---
[18631.014985] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Q 30 is active and mapped to fifo 2 ra_tid 0xa5a5 [90,1515870810]
```

Comment: Ubuntu 16.10 (Yakkety Yak) End of Life reached on July 20, 2017. You are no longer receiving security updates.

Comment: Sorry, the correct version of my ubuntu is 16.04.05 LTS